add-in Action button does not work on Outlook new and Web
I've created an outlook add-in. The purpose of this add-in is to call a script java function found on an html page hosted online. The problem I'm having is that on outlook desktop the add-in works fine. But on outlook new and web here's what I get as an error message:
"We're sorry, we couldn't access `myAddin`. Make sur you have a network connection. If the problem continues, please try again later.
Here is my "Action button" code:
<DesktopFormFactor>
    <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
            <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                    <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                        <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>openNewTab</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                </Control>
            </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
    </ExtensionPoint>
</DesktopFormFactor>

I haven't tried much because I don't understand where the problem comes from.
